# Creating Greatest Common denominator program, but problem with array parameter

Tags: java

I am trying to find the GCD of the array listed below. However, I am not able to access the array when I call for it. I get the error

```
GCD.java:4: error: illegal start of expression
        generalizedGCD({2,4,6,8,10});
GCD.java:4: error: not a statement
        generalizedGCD({2,4,6,8,10});
```

How do I fix this?

```
    import java.util.Arrays; 
    public class GCD{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        generalizedGCD({2,4,6,8,10});
    {

        public static int generalizedGCD(int [] arr){

                Arrays.sort(arr);
                int largest = arr[i];

            for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `new int[]` in front of your `{2,4,6,8,10}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had lot of issues. You can use something like this to easily find the GCD of an array,

```
public class GCD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = generalizedGCD(new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10});
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static int generalizedGCD(int[] arr) {
        int i = 1;
        int result = arr[0];

        while (i < arr.length) {
            if (arr[i] % result == 0) {
                i++;
            } else {
                result = arr[i] % result;
                i++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I output the result variable? System.out.println(result)?

Comment: You can simply print the result by printing the returning value when you call the method. I have updated the code

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
generalizedGCD({2,4,6,8,10});
```

Does not properly construct a new `Array`. Use

```
generalizedGCD(new int[]{2,4,6,8,10});
```

Instead to construct an `Array` and pass it to the method

---

Also note that you have some unbalanced parenthesis in your code

Answer (score 1):

I have mixed two things.

#### Array variable declaration

```
int[] arr = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
generalizedGCD(arr);
```

#### Method parameter definition

```
generalizedGCD(new int[] {2, 4, 6, 8, 10});
```